# PHP, MySQL Application with Mobile apps

Tags: php, mobile, express, meteor

I'm planning to develop PHP eCommerce application with MySQl database as a backend. I'm planning to develop Mobile application for this application.

Which technology should I use so that I can create Business logic (Business Layer) and Data Logic (Data Layer) at once and keep reusing the same across all the platforms (Windows/Web/Mobile/Mac/Linux/etc). I don't want to recreate the same logic again and again. I'm planning to create native apps for Android,Windows,IOS platforms and connect to common database. I welcome all valuable suggestions.
And also please suggest whether can I use Web Service or RESTFull Web Service or Meteor.js or Express.js for this scenario.

Thanks in Advance.Waiting for valuable reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a data services server. From them you can easily create web services from database with security.

For advance data services framework see WSO2 Data services server.
http://wso2.com/products/data-services-server/

For simple PHP/MySQL data services framework, you can use PHPDS.
http://chaturadilan.github.io/PHP-Data-Services/

Both are open sourced and free to use